# Facing issues while executing SQL command using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In my controller, I have this method:

```
def show
    @final =final_params
    allparams=''
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("USE database")
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("declare @p3 dbo.Params")
    @final.each do |key, value|
      allparams= "insert into @p3 values(N'""#{key}"+"'"++",N'"+"#{value}"+"')\n"
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(allparams)
    end
  end
```

But, I am facing the below error:

```
TinyTds::Error: Must declare the table variable "@p3".: insert into @p3 values(N'a',N'aa')
```

In my above code `@p3` is a table name parameter.

**I am using SQL Server for database.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call stored procedure in ruby on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496919/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: I have changed my method so that I can execute SQL statements as below: 

    def show
    @final =final_params
    allparams=''
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("USE database")
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("declare @p3 dbo.FormParams")
    @final.each do |key, value|
      allparams= "insert into @p3 values(N'""#{key}"+"'"++",N'"+"#{value}"+"')\n"
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(allparams)
    end
  end


But now, I am facing the below error: 
`TinyTds::Error: Must declare the table variable "@p3".: insert into @p3 values(N'a',N'aa')`

Comment: Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50077058/edit) instead of including (or changing) details in the comments, it will be easier for everyone to understand your problem and more likely to receive a helpful answer.

Comment: Updated @Gerry. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`#{@p3}`, but this code looks like vulnerable to SQL-injection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to interpolate the `@p3` variable into the sql string assigned to `allparams`, like this:

```
@final.each do |key, value|
  allparams = "insert into #{@p3} values(N'""#{key}"+"'"++",N'"+"#{value}"+"')\n"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(allparams)
end
```